# Should i use nginx for my image hosting site with high traffic?

Tags: apache, optimization, nginx

I am suggested by a friend to use nginx for my site http://www.imgzzz.com . its an image hosting site with loads of traffic.

Currently im on a vps ..CentOS 5.4 x64 , Apache

Most views are on image pages. So far to decrease the load on server i have done cache of almost all data like user details, image name, path, category details etc.

Still i have to go with about 3 sql queries every page/view.

1. Addition of Views
2. Displaying Views
3. Addition of user ad views with respect to their ads shown

Considering the traffic from social media sites like digg, stumbleupon. per second online user peaks upto 1500-2500. So i guess you can get the idea of php queries per second.. Sometimes it causes the server to lag.

The rest of the stuff on  image pages is static. So now do you guys suggest nginx or any other better option for my server?

Thanks in advance :) 
Edit : This is a custom system not any cms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using nginx as your static file server.  I run nginx for this and it works great, and I could vouch for alot of other people I know that uses it.  It's fast and reliable.

Comment: So it will be fine even with the number of sql queries per second in taffic spikes?

Comment: Absolutely - probably the best HTTP/Proxy server you could use for the "static" jobs you are referring to.  I'm assuming your custom application is going to run the queries and then the nginx instance would serve out the static files.  If this is the case, definately go with nginx - I wouldn't recommend anything else.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. :)